# Mongo db connection problems

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

i have a really annoying problem with mongo db connections.
I`m using symfony2 and Mongo db php library(i don`t use ODM). From time to time for no reason the connection fails with an error something like:

```
"Failed to connect to: 54.246.115.206:27017: Previous connection attempts failed, server blacklisted"
```

> Unable to connect MongoDB, please check your configurations. MongoDB
>   said:Failed to connect to: 54.246.115.206:27017: Previous connection
>   attempts failed, server blacklisted.

I read in the web about this problem and the explanation was that the connection is persistant and you should check if the connection hasn`t timed out and if not use it, if it is make a new one. I make the connection via this code:

```
      private function getMongoConnection($server, $user, $pass, $retry = 3) {
        try {
            return new \MongoClient($server, array("username" => $user, "password" => $pass, 'connect' => true));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            /* Log the exception so we can look into why mongod failed later */
//            \MongoClient::close();
            logException($e);
        }
        if ($retry > 0) {
            return $this->getMongoConnection($server, $user, $pass, --$retry);
        }
        throw new Exception("I've tried several times getting MongoClient.. Is mongod really running?");
    }
```

I`m still getting the above show errors ...

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the value of $server?

This usually happens when connecting to a ReplicaSet and one of the servers goes down.
To prevent the driver from flooding the server (that we know is down) with connection attempts on every request, we blacklist the server instead for few seconds and try again later.

Note that the seedlist ($server) cannot contain space between the server list. The servers are separated by a comma (,).